# Is there any guarantee that results of globbing will be sorted in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, glob

Is there any guarantee that the array of filenames returned from a glob (e.g. `<*>`) will be sorted?

I can't find that sorting is mentioned one way or the other [in the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), but it seems to be the case in every directory I've tried it on.

I'm talking about using this syntax:

```
@files = <*>;
```

If I need the files to be sorted, would the below be redundant?

```
@files = sort(<*>);
```

Comment: `s/$files/@files/` ? The glob operator and sort function return lists.

Comment: @mobrule thanks, fixed. i do most of my work in PHP, where $ is used on all variable types. :-[

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Perl 5.6.0 and newer, filenames are sorted:

> Beginning with v5.6.0, this operator
>   is implemented using the standard
>   File::Glob  extension.

-- [perldoc for glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

> By default, the pathnames are sorted
>   in ascending ASCII order.

-- [perldoc for File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html)

There is one catch:

> By default, file names are assumed to
>   be case sensitive

-- [perldoc for File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html)

Having said all that, you can change this behavior to sort case-insensitively with

```
use File::Glob qw(:globally :nocase);
```

Note that :globally is redundant since 5.6.0, but this will work on older versions as well.

Alternately, if you just want to do a single glob with case-insensitivity:

```
use File::Glob ':glob';

@files = bsd_glob('*', GLOB_NOCASE);
```

Comment: thanks, I guess I didn't notice the bit about File::Glob being used internally now