# Perl - Rename and Sort Image Files

Tags: regex, perl

I have some images I want to Rename and sort, but when I rename them they aren't renaming in the same order. I’m getting the output I want but they are not sorted from the original. Really what I’m asking is how to match and substitute the example below .

```
Code is current output:
image_1_0.jpg -> 6.jpg
image_1_1.jpg -> 4.jpg

Code output wanted:
image_1_0.jpg -> 1.jpg
image_1_1.jpg -> 2.jpg
```

images folder

```
image_1_0.jpg
image_1_1.jpg
image_2_0.jpg
image_2_1.jpg
image_3_1.jpg
image_3_2.jpg
image_3_3.jpg
image_4_0.jpg
image_5_0.jpg
```

output would be

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
```

Here's what I have

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file;
my @imagesFile;
my $counter = 0;

my $dir = 'usr/local/bin/images';

opendir (IMGDIR, "$dir") or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
@imagesFile = (readdir(IMGDIR));
closedir IMGDIR;

foreach my $file(@imagesFile){
$counter++;

rename "$dir/$file", "$dir/$counter.jpg";

}
```

Could use some insight on this issue.

Comment: Really what I’m asking is how to match and substitute image_1_0.jpg for 1.jpg etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readdir` isn't going to return the filenames in sorted order. If you want the images to be in some order as you increment their final names, you have to do that yourself.

```
my @files = sort readdir($dh);
```

And, you probably want to at least remove the `.` and `..` virtual directories, as well as any other files you don't want to target. Even better is selecting the files that you do want:

```
my @files = sort grep /image_\d_\d.jpg/, readdir($dh);
```

Comment: Only thing is what if I have an image_10_0 or image_11_0 . It's not renaming those greater than 9. I tried my @files = sort grep ^[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]$, readdir($dh), but then that's only remaining image_10_0 through image_20_0 and not image_1_0 through image_9_0.

Comment: Then adjust the regex to fit whatever you want to accept. I'm showing you a technique, not writing your code.

Answer (score 2):

Please inspect following code for compliance with your requirements.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;

my $counter = 0;

rename $_, ++$counter . '.jpg' for sort glob("*.jpg");
```

Comment: `glob` is the better solution, but I would wish for a better description of your answer. Also, `glob` sorts its output as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461552/725418). Small optimization, perhaps.

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you explained why this would work. Code isn't enough for people who are already struggling with code.